# Problems with process created using 32bit python on Debian 5.0 IA-64

Tags: python, executable, subprocess

So, the problem is with creating processes - all of them immediately return with exit code -9.
I tried to use subprocess.Popen module and os.popen2, os.system and some other. Nothing helps.
I'm using python 2.5.

I have a python binary executable built on 32bit platform with 32bit python using pyinstaller. This is very important and I know that the best way to make it working is to create ia64 executable. But currently I'm looking for more common solution. It possibly exists cause on several other IA64 machines it worked.

Have anybody faced similar problem?

Comment: What do your subprocess method calls look like?

Comment: for example > subprocess.Popen(['ping', '127.0.0.1'])